# Is there really no way to apply a css class in a TD in gmail?

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

I have to send a (complex) html-mail to various receivers and desperately try to bring it to work for various email clients (at least Outlook, iOS and gmail).

I now have a version that works for Outlook and iOS, but **not** for gmail (Android).
**Short description:**
There are various css styles and media queries defined in the header.
The css class **conttext** (see snipped below) defines the font family, font size, and so on..
The css class **conttextboldblue** (see snipped below) set the attributes: color: #0000FF; (blue) font-weight: bold;
The class conttext is set to the **td** element and works on any platform.
The class conttextboldblue is set in **span** in the **td** and works on all platforms (including  GC that I use for tests) **except gmail.**
If I set the style **inline** (last row in the snipped below), it works in gmail, but all other clients **lose** the styles set in conttext (font family, font size and so on).
As I worte above, it's a huge and complex email and I don't want to remove all css styles and put anything inline (further, I also need media queries).
I have searched the internet and also SO and only found, that - if a css style to **td** is defined, all other css styles are removed in gmail... :-(
And.. that exactly seems to be the case...
**Therefore my question:**
**- Does anybody have a solution to bring that to work also in gmail?**
**Thanks for any hint!**

Code **snipped**:

```
<td><span class="conttext"><br>
Some text <strong>some strong text</strong> mit <strong>some strong text</strong> some text<br>
<br>
Some text <br>
</span>
<span class="conttextboldblue">This text is NOT (only in gMail) not formatted -> conttextboldblue is just ignored</span><br>

<span style="color:blue; font-weight:bold;">This text is formatted but all other clients (iOS und Outlook) lose the formats defined in conttext!</span><br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here now my findings...
**In general:**
Our html email contains images (with links), special formats to text (bold, blue, red) tables, bullets, internal links and has to be sent to about 12k recipient’s, whereby we do not know, on what devices they will read the email.
A few years ago, we have optimized a similar email only for desktop (Outlook). These times are over definitely - we have to expect, that **more than 50%** will read the email on mobile devices (this is **fact**).
It’s incredible complex and time consuming to create such an email, that is at least readable without problems on desktop (Outlook) and mobiles (iOS (iOS mail app) and Android (gmail)).

**Noted (main) issues (to my specific html email):**

- Outlook need a smaller font size and a fix width for the table and also the images to look O.K.
- Outlook further need special settings for bullets, that are not compatible with the mobile clients.
- Outlook and iOS (and any browser, e.g. Google Chrome) respect css-stiles (set with “class=”) and media queries - whereby I have not found a way to bring this at work with gmail. For me, it seems as gmail delete all css-settings after opening the email (maybe there is a way to bring it to work, but I gave up after a few days of try and error). The only that works (for me), is to apply styles (style =) directly to the html elements. If have found some information’s that it also works in gmail, but with (massive) limitations https://litmus.com/community/discussions/8098-media-queries-support-for-android-gmail-app-2019-verison
- The mobile clients need a viewport entry and to set images and tables to 100%, else the email is scaled automatically to a not to read “micro font” (and the users have to zoom to be able to read the text)
- Internal links work on Outlook and Android, but not in iOS (else iOS has good support for css and the behavior is, as it should be)

I have not found a real “solution” but (only) a **workaround**.
**Viewport entry:**

```
 <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

In the **style tag** it set all css **for outlook** (width to images and table, font size and “special” settings for bullets (**wrong** for the mobile clients).

```
ul, ol{margin-left: 20px !important;}
li {text-align:-webkit-match-parent; display:list-item;text-indent: -1em; margin-top: 5px;}
```

Then I set base settings f**or iOS mobiles** in a media query

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
/* Reset Spezialeinstellungen Outlook für alle Mobiles*/
ul,ol {margin-left: 0px; }
li {text-align:left; display:list-item;text-indent: 0px; margin-top: 0px;}
.HauptTabelle {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

This resets the outlook special settings for all iOS clients with max width of 1024px.

Then I set css for various iOS devices - example:

```
/*IPhone 6/7/8: 375px */
@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
.conttext {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    line-height: 22px !important;
}
.Headline0Boldleft {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    line-height: 22px !important; 
}
.headline {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    line-height: 22px !important; 
}
.headtext {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    line-height: 22px !important; 
}
.conttextboldblue {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    line-height: 22px!important; 
}
.conntextbold {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    line-height: 22px !important;
}
}
```

And then, I set the attributes for **Android (gmail)** in addition direct to the html elements.
Example:

```
<td style="color: #0000FF; font-weight: bold; border: 2px solid #FF0000; padding:4px !important;" class="style1"><span class="conttextboldblue">Some text... and further code...
```

In this example, I set the font color to red and bold and a border.
Note: the same is defined in classes **style1** (border and padding) and **conttextboldblue**.
So...I set the attributes **double** (on time inline with Style= and onetime in the css classes).
Android (gmail) only respect the "style=", whereby iOS takes the css style **with priority**.
So I can define further styles (e.g. font size) for iOS in media queries.
Android (gmail) seems to apply a “usable” font size automatically.

As mentioned above, this is not a solution, but a workaround for **my** case.
If I would have further html mails to send out in the future (what is not the case), I would invest (a lot) more time to find a real solution...

**Further hints:**
Validate your html code here:
https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload
Note: The tool shows double assigned styles (inline and with css) as error, but it works nevertheless

Take care, that you have the correct notation to comment lines:
**CSS:**

```
/* Your comment */
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Your comment -->
```

(my editor has commented lines in css as html comments, what has cost me some time until I noted that...)

Load your html email in **Google Chrome**, press F12 (debug mode) and check it there (especially, if you have media queries in your html).
If you have media queries and GC don’t show it, something is wrong with your code.
With GC you easily can simulate mobiles and have a look, if the media queries are applied correct.

I hope, this helps somebody...

Answer (score 2):

Not all versions of Gmail are equal, and not all of them support `<style>` elements. In particular, if you test in Gmail (Android or iOS) with a third party email address (like an `@outlook.com` address for example), you won't get support for `<style>` and only inline styles will work there. (I wrote [a blog post about Gmail CSS support here](https://www.hteumeuleu.com/2019/trying-to-make-sense-of-gmail-css-support-2019-edition/).)

Gmail clients are also known for being picky about any misformed CSS and removing entire `<style>` tags if they see something they don't like. For example, having a rule like `@media { @font-face { … }}` will get Gmail (all clients) to remove the entire `<style>` element that contain these rules. (But feel free to post your entire code to get detailed feedback on this precisely.)

For these reasons, it is usually considered a best practice to inline your styles in an HTML email.

Comment: Thanks for your posting. I have done some further tests and now see, that it's worse than expected . It seems, as ALL css are ignored from gmail. As I worte, I need media queries (these are placed normally in the head- and style-tag. Can media queres be placed in the html code (body)  and will they work with outlook and iOS?

Comment: Support for `<style>` (and thus media queries) is inequal (see https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-style/ for details). I would really recommend you to post your entire code for further help.

Comment: It seems as I have found a workaround now for my needs. I now have to change my code and retest it. If I come to an "usable" end, I will post my findings here (as answer).